# What's the correct terminology for the backup problem caused by reorganising files?

Tags: backup, file-transfer

If I backup a number of directories, then move a file between directories, a full backup will normally copy that file again, even if it hasn't changed.

I believe a normal incremental backup will also recopy the file. But I also think some backup systems manage to avoid doing so, by keeping track of already-copied files.

Is there a standard term for this problem or for the software feature which mitigates it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the term should be '[deduplication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_deduplication)'

Comment: Look for a backup solution that keeps each unique file only once no matter how many time's it appears on the system.  This is usually done by generating hashes (MD5 commonly) and indexing/storing the files based on this data.

Comment: @Chris Nava: what you describe is called 'deduplication' :)